# Unexplained empty memory address before .data section

Tags: ld, stm32, elf, hex-file

I'm currently writing a program on STM32 that uses a simple bootloader and two sub-applications. The sub-applications are located in flash memory and the bootloader loads one of them (both code and data) into the RAM memory and then starts executing it. The copying is done simply by iterating over the addresses in flash and copying data from these addresses to RAM.

Recently I've encountered some strange bug. I was trying to read some data from a globally defined array. I was getting back wrong values, e.g. when I tried to read `array[0]` I was getting back the value of `array[1]`.

I did some debugging and disassembly of the .elf and .hex files and I think I've found the cause of this bug. It turned out that there is an empty space between the `.ARM` section of the .elf file of this project.
Surprisingly, this empty space is not present in the .hex file (which I use for flashing the STM32 board).
This is what I am talking about:

- .elf file:

```
2000ee70:   469e        mov lr, r3
2000ee72:   4770        bx  lr

Disassembly of section .ARM:

2000ee74 <__exidx_start>:
2000ee74:   7fff267c    svcvc   0x00ff267c
2000ee78:   00000001    andeq   r0, r0, r1

Disassembly of section .data:

2000ee80 <evnames.5255>:
2000ee80:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
2000ee84:   08030104    stmdaeq r3, {r2, r8}
```

- .hex file:

```
 802de70:   4770469e    
 802de74:   7fff267c    svcvc   0x00ff267c
 802de78:   00000001    andeq   r0, r0, r1
 802de7c:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
 802de80:   08030104    stmdaeq r3, {r2, r8}
```

Obviously, the addresses are different because the addresses in the .elf file are VMA and the addresses in the .hex file are LMA.
What I've noticed here is that after the `.ARM` section, the next memory address should be `2000ee7C` but from unknown reasons, the `.data` section begins at `2000ee80`. So there is one unexplained, empty word between them. But this empty word is not present in the .hex file. The `00000001` is immediately followed by `00000000`.
So basically, I think the disassembly of the .hex file should output the following result:

```
 802de70:   4770469e    
 802de74:   7fff267c    svcvc   0x00ff267c
 802de78:   00000001    andeq   r0, r0, r1
 802de7c:       <something here>
 802de80:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
 802de84:   08030104    stmdaeq r3, {r2, r8}
```

Because of this empty memory space, which disappears in the .hex file, when my bootloader loads the data to RAM, the `array[0]` which LMA is `2000eec8` ends up being at the address `2000eec4`.

This is the troubling snippet of the linker script that I use:

```
  /* ARM specific sections, they also go to FLASH and are copied to RAM */
  .ARM.extab : { 
      *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*) 
  } > RAMAPP AT> FLASH_APP
  .ARM : {
      __exidx_start = .;
      *(.ARM.exidx*)
      __exidx_end = .;
  } > RAMAPP AT> FLASH_APP

  /* Initialized data sections - variables etc.  */
  .data :
  {
      . = ALIGN(4);
      *(.data)           /* .data sections */
      *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */
      . = ALIGN(4);    
  } >RAMAPP AT> FLASH_APP /* Data section is placed in FLASH_APP but its Virtual Memory Address is in RAM_APP */
```

I use the following command to link the .o files into one .elf file:

```sh
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wl,--gc-sections -mthumb -mthumb-interwork -mcpu=cortex-m4 --specs=nosys.specs -L[path_to_library_files] -T[path_to_ld_file] [long_list_of_object_files] -o [output_elf_file]
```

I use the following command to convert the .elf file into the .hex file:

```sh
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O ihex [elf_file] [output_hex_file]
```

I've tried to experiment with the parameters I give to the `arm-none-eabi-objcopy` and `arm-none-eabi-gcc` to get rid of this padding, for example `--file-alignment` or `--gap-fill` but to no success so far.

Does anyone have an idea about where does this empty space come from and how to get rid of it (or include it in the .hex file)?

**EDIT:** According to the suggestions from the first two comments, I've tried:
 * using the newest versions of `arm-none-eabi-gcc` and `arm-none-eabi-objcopy` in my toolchain,
 * `ALIGN(4)` of the `.ARM` section,
 * not copying the `.ARM` section to RAM.
Unfortunately, none of these solutions fixed this problem.

What I've noticed recently is that sometimes the data is aligned correctly in the `.elf` file (the first address of the `.data` section is the address that immediately follows the end of the `.ARM` section). It depends on the address where the `.ARM` section happens to end. I can manipulate that by adding some extra function invocations in the code (resulting in the larger `.text` area), for example:

```
2000ee84:   469e        mov lr, r3
2000ee86:   4770        bx  lr

Disassembly of section .ARM:

2000ee88 <__exidx_start>:
2000ee88:   7fff2668    svcvc   0x00ff2668
2000ee8c:   00000001    andeq   r0, r0, r1

Disassembly of section .data:

2000ee90 <evnames.5255>:
2000ee90:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
2000ee94:   2001111c    andcs   r1, r1, ip, lsl r1
```

This way, I've estabilished that:
 * when `.ARM` section ends at address `0x*******0` the `.data` section incorrectly starts at `0x*******8` (should be `0x*******4`)
 * when `.ARM` section ends at address `0x*******8` the `.data` section incorrectly starts at `0x*******0` (should be `0x*******C`)
 * when `.ARM` section ends at address `0x*******4` the `.data` section CORRECTLY starts at `0x*******8`
 * when `.ARM` section ends at address `0x*******C` the `.data` section CORRECTLY starts at `0x*******0`

Comment: Have you tried different compiler (different version) ? I remember hitting an absurd problem with `objcopy` and addressing some time ago, but after switching `gcc` version problem dissapeard so i forgot about it. You tried to `ALIGN` `.ARM` section and see what happens ?

Comment: It stands out to me that `.ARM` sections are copied to RAM. Can you simplify and publish the full source with linker scripts?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! Addressed them in the EDIT of my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, It turned out I had to add `ALIGN_WITH_INPUT` to the .data section in the linker script. Like this:

```
  .data : ALIGN_WITH_INPUT
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */
    . = ALIGN(4);    

  } >RAMAPP AT> FLASH_APP
```

This parameter causes the LMAs of the section to be aligned in the same way the VMAs are.
Now the alignment in the .hex file is identical to the one in the .elf file.
Shout out to reddit user FreddieChopin who helped me to resolve this issue.